# How do I use inputstream in python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, if-statement

I have this line of code:

```
incoming = input("Type in 1 or 2")

if incoming == 1:
    print ("you entered 1")
elif incoming == 2:
    print ("you entered 2")
```

this worked perfectly fine when I used python 2... on my mac, but on windows with python 3, not so well.

Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: input() returns a string.....

Comment: in if-else structure replace incoming with int(incoming)

Comment: That's because in python 2 `input(prompt)` was roughly equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.

Comment: any idea why it worked on mac with python 2.7?

Comment: With that in mind, read ["Is using eval in python a bad practice?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3.x doesn't evaluate and convert data types the way Python 2.x did. So, you are going to have to explicitly convert your user's input to an integer like this:

```
incoming = int(input("Type 1 or 2: "))
```